# Writing unittests for a function which calls a subprocess to run git commands

Tags: python, git, subprocess, python-unittest

I have written a function which opens up the editor to edit commit message when called. It looks something like:

```py
def apply():
    return subprocess.run(['git', 'commit', '-o', '--amend'])
```

This function is called in another function and I am trying to write unit tests for that function. The problem is that this function opens a editor when called.

So I thought of passing the commit message as a input to subprocess when it is called in unit test.

```py
def apply(msg=None):
    if msg is None
        return subprocess.run(['git', 'commit', '-o', '--amend'])
    else:
        return subprocess.run(['git', 'commit', '-o', '--amend'], input=msg)
```

But this is giving the following error

```
 Too many errors from stdintor to close the file... 
 Buffer written to /home/projects/xrides/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG.save.7
 error: There was a problem with the editor 'editor'.
```

Comment: You should mock `subprocess.run` for the test.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency injection approach is fine, you just need to add the `-m`/`--message` argument to `git` command line and pass the message (not via STDIN like you're doing):

```
subprocess.run(['git', 'commit', '-o', '--amend', '--message', msg])
```

So:

```
def apply(msg=None):
    if msg is None
        return subprocess.run(['git', 'commit', '-o', '--amend'])
    else:
        return subprocess.run(['git', 'commit', '-o', '--amend', '--message', msg])
```

---

Another approach would be to mock the `subprocess.run` object in test so that it returns a custom value that you can check against or validate further.